# The meaning of "with many delays"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Is "with many delays" a common idiom, and in which cases can it be used?

Are there other ways to express the same meaning?

For example,

- Life comes with many delays.
- He went to look for him, with many delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this does not seem to me to fit the definition of an idiom. An idiom is something like: "He was caught red-handed." That means, he was caught in the act of doing something (usually something wrong). It's as if someone has blood on their hands, signifying their guilt. The meaning of your phrase is readily understandable from the words themselves.

So, I would say it is a phrase. You would use it when you want to describe anything that, well, involves many delays.  For example: Her husband arrived home from work, after many delays.

You should not have trouble finding others.

"After much delay" is an alternative. Words that are synonyms of delay should generally work as replacements. You might investigate the words "holdup" and "setback" as alternatives.

I wouldn't want to hazard an opinion on how common it is, but I would say you would tend to see it more in literary settings than common speech. If I told my wife, "Honey, I'm home now, with many delays," she would know what I meant but she might think it odd.